# Is it possible to turn all the pixels of an image to black and recover back the original image later?

Tags: matlab

Considering a picture as a frame of any video.I am developing a code for a pay-per-view TV system for cable TV, that's why I want to use a key at the transmitter end to bitxor (bitwise xor) all the RGB pixels or just one colour to do something which results in a black or white screen. I have wrote this code, but still I can see that picture with some pixels colour scattered.

I want to use some technique through which the picture turns black or white to protect my video from unsubscribers and recover the original picture from this black or white pic for later use.

```
img=imread('pepper.png');
[imr,imc,clr]=size(img);

for row=1:imr
    for col=1:imc
        for k=1:clr             
          if(k==1) 
             img2(row,col,k)=bitxor(img(row,col,k),66);
          else
             img2(row,col,k)=img(row,col,k);   
          end
        end
    end
end
imwrite(img2,'pepper.png');
imshow(img2);
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? If you save a standard image format to all black, then no you cannot go back.

Comment: If your title is longer than your question body, then chances are that you should rephrase the question. Please explain what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I am developing a code for pay per view TV system for cable Tv, thats y i want to use a key at the transmitter end to bitxor (bitwise xor) all the rgb pixels or just one colour to do something which results in a black or white screen. I have wrote this code but still i can see that picture with some pixels clour scattered.

Comment: I passed by to notice you basically changed your question into something quite different. Anyway, I updated my answer a bit

Answer (score 4):

Strictly speaking: no. When you store black(i.e. color #000000), you cannot recover the previous contents.

You can however store your data elsewhere, e.g. inside the meta-data, but I wonder what good that would do.

I suspect you only want your image to look like black to the naked eye. That can be done at a cost (either in size, loss of information or visibility). There are some things you could do, just intuitively:

1. Very lossy: just put all colors to a color very near to black, but according to the contents of your image, you just put a slightly brighter or darker black at positions where your image is brighter/darker. That way the image seems black, but you can recover some information (not an exact replica of the original, obviously). In this way I expect you to be able to store 1 or 2 bits per pixel per color (instead of 8 as in the original image)
2. Just a small extension on the previous principle. If you want perfect reconstruction and allow for your image size to grow, that is possible. You just map 1 pixel in the original image to 4, 9, 16, ... pixels in the "black" image. E.g. if you choose 9 pixels, you store the first bit plane of the original image in the first set of pixels, second bit plane in the second set, ... (and the 9th set of pixels is just pitch black).

You can of course devise some scheme to mix the pixels around, such that only looking at the bit planes of your almost black image will yield little visual clue. In reconstructing the image, you will have to reverse this.

Obviously, these examples are just quick ways to do such a thing, anyone familiar with  [steganography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography) will know these tricks (and of course better techniques) and might try them out to reverse them if they suspect something.

Answer (score 3):

Recovering destroyed information is impossible, why would anyone store in coloured images if that was possible?

Re your edit: If you use XOR (or any other arbitrary operation) to obtain (I hesitate to call that encrypt) a purely black or white image, that means the information required for "decrypting" is the original image itself (since only `(a XOR b) XOR b = a` unless you use some `mod` operation or similar). But why don't you simply use one of the already existing encryptions to render the encrypted image into seemingly garbage? Also, have a look at wikipedia's entry on [Conditional access](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_access) for some inspiration.

Comment: @Farooq: how did you land a job encrypting the video feeds of a cable TV firm if you know nothing about encryption??

Answer (score 1):

That reminds me of the 2008 challenge to the Underhanded C Contest: http://underhanded.xcott.com/?p=8

Answer (score 1):

This is my stupid solution but it works enough for my needs:
Not in Matlab but a general algorithm to scramble the image.

```
private void BitmapObfuscator(ref Bitmap img, bool obfuscate)
{
    BitmapData d = img.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, img.Width, img.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    for (int y = 0; y < d.Height; y++) {
        unsafe
        {
            byte* row = (byte*)d.Scan0 + (y * d.Stride);
            for (int x = 0; x < d.Stride; x+=d.Stride / d.Width) {
                byte* pixelR = row + x;
                byte* pixelG = row + x + 1;
                byte* pixelB = row + x + 2;
                int shift = (x * y) % 10;
                if (shift > 8) shift = 4;
                switch (shift) {
                    case 1:
                    case 2:
                    case 3:
                    case 4:
                        *pixelR = (byte)(255 - *pixelR);
                        *pixelG = (byte)(255 - *pixelG);
                        *pixelB = (byte)(255 - *pixelB);
                        break;
                }
                int pixel = *pixelR << 16 | *pixelG << 8 | *pixelB;

                if (obfuscate)
                {
                    pixel = pixel << 4;
                    byte surplus = (byte)(pixel >> 24);
                    pixel |= surplus;
                }
                else {
                    byte surplus = (byte)(*pixelB & (byte)0x0F);
                    pixel = pixel >> 4; 
                    pixel |= surplus << 20;
                }
                *pixelR = (byte)(pixel >> 16);
                *pixelG = (byte)(pixel >> 8 & 0x000000FF);
                *pixelB = (byte)(pixel & 0x000000FF);
            }
        }
    }
    img.UnlockBits(d);
}
```

It garbles the picture enough to make it unrecognizable, but the algorithm can get back the  original.

Maybe it can help you, I'm sure you can translate it to mathlab somehow.

In case you wonder why the 'switch': this method is vulnerable to few-color images, this make it less so.

These are the outputs:
[image: garbled output]

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep a copy of your color image.

```
rgb_I = imread('yourcolorimage.jpg');
gray_I = rgb2gray(rgb_I);
imwrite(gray_I,'yourblackimage.jpg');
imshow(rgb_I);
```